# How to justify that $\text{Var}\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\Big) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n\text{Var}(X_i)$

Tags: random-variables, variance

In the [sum of uncorrelated variables (Bienaymé formula)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), it is stated that
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}\Big(\bar{X}\Big) &= \text{Var}\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\Big)\tag{1}\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n\text{Var}(X_i)\tag{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sigma^2\\
&=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}
\end{align*}
$$

How do we justify the changes going from (1) to (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align*}\text{Var}\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\Big) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)^2\right) - \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)\right)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)^2\right) - \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n\text{Var}(X_i),
\end{align*}$

where in the second equality we used the fact that $\mathbb{E}$ is linear and for the third equality you need to use that $X_i's$ are uncorrelated. More precisely, you should use the following equality:

$Var(X + X^{\prime}) = Var(X) + Var(X^{\prime}) + 2Cov(X, X^{\prime}) = Var(X) + Var(X^{\prime})$,

when $X$ and $X^{\prime}$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @LuisaBorsato. Shouldn't the last term on the first line be $\Big(\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)\Big)^2$ instead?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely! :) I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

Well $\operatorname{Var}(cY)=c^2\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ is true for any random variable with second moment and any $c$.

Furthermore, we see that if $Y$ and $Z$ have second moment, then, by bi-linearity of the covariance,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var} (Z+Y)&=\operatorname{Cov}(Z+Y,Z+Y)\\
&=\operatorname{Cov}(Z,Z)+\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z)+\operatorname{Cov}(Z,Y)+\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Y)\\
&=\operatorname{Var(Z)}+\operatorname{Var(Z)}+2\operatorname{Cov}(Z,Y)
\end{align}

Hence, if $\operatorname{Cov}(Z,Y)=0$, then $\operatorname{Var}(Z+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(Z)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$. You can proceed by induction if you wish.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @WoolierThanThou. What do you mean by "have second moment"?

Comment: That $\mathbb{E} Y^2<\infty$ so that it has a well-defined variance.